# How to save the formatting from a text widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter, widget

I am building a text editor. I am using tags with Text widget, but when I try to save it, the text is saved normally without any formatting. I have tried saving it as `txt` and `rtf`.
Here is the code for saving:

```
def filesave():
    file1=open("txt.rtf",'w')
    text=str(textbox.get("1.0",END))
    file1.write(text)
    file1.close()
```

And here is the code I am using for tagging (shortened), just in case anybody needs it:

```
from Tkinterimport *
textbox=Text()
textbox.pack()

textbox.tag_config("BOLD",font="-weight bold")
textbox.tag_config("ITAL",font="-slant italic")
textbox.tag_config("ULIN",font="-underline 1")

def make_bold():
    textbox.tag_add("BOLD","sel.first","sel.last")

def make_ital():
    textbox.tag_add("ITAL","sel.first","sel.last")

def make_ulin():
    textbox.tag_add("ULIN","sel.first","sel.last")
```

I am calling the functions with buttons.

How do I save the text in the Text Widget with all the tags in `html` or `rtf` or `docx` or anything that can be read again by my text editor?